# Resteasy UriBuilder incorrectly encodes?

Tags: java, rest, uri, resteasy

I am trying to create a URI from a string url using UriBuilder from RestEasy and I am getting some unexpected results. I am running the following piece of code.

`UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8190/items?pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}");`

`System.out.println(uriBuilder.build(1, 10));`

Expected result:

`http://localhost:8190/items?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10`

Actual result:

`http://localhost:8190/items%3FpageNumber=1&pageSize=10`

When using UriBuilder.fromUri() instead of fromPath() it throws an exception while creating the URI

`Illegal character in query at index 39: http://localhost:8190/items?pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}`

the character at 39 is {.

I don't want to parse the complete string to create the URI part by part.

I looked at the RestEasy code and it is encoding the '?' character while creating the builder using org.jboss.resteasy.util.Encode#encode using the pathEncoding map from org.jboss.resteasy.util.Encode#pathEncoding.

Is my usage incorrect or the implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) is a JAX-RS implementation, from the Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#fromPath%28java.lang.String%29) of `fromPath`:

> Create a new instance representing a **relative** URI initialized from a URI path.

I think it was not intended for absolute URLs, hence I'm afraid the answer is that your usage is incorrect.

You will need something like [this](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features#OverviewofJAX-RS1.0Features-BuildingURIs) (didn't test it though)

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8190/").
  path("{a}").
  queryParam("pageNumber", "{pageNumber}").
  queryParam("pageSize", "{pageSize}").
  build("items", 1,10);
```

Comment: Yes, that approach worked. Thanks! It's not about absolute or relative URLs, just that if there are query parameters the question mark is also encoded and it does not work.